# jQuery .append is occurring multiple times. How do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, frontend

I looked at some similar posts, but haven't found the solution I'm looking for.  I am attempting to append `div#dropdownmenu` only once.  However, it continues to occur as I hover over the div.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function () {
    if ($('div#dropmenu').length == 0) {
        $('#site_nav > ul > a').live('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).append("<div></div>");
            $('#site_nav > ul > li a div').attr('id', 'dropmenu');
            $('div#dropmenu').html("<ul></ul>");
            $('div#dropmenu ul').html("<li><a>Mission</a></li><li><a>Story</a></li><li><a>Quality</a></li><li><a>Pledge</a></li><li><a>Bio</a></li>");
        });
    } else {
        $('#site_nav > ul > li > a').append("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML this is being applied to?

Comment: you're appending to `#site_nav` but checking the length of `div#dropmenu` is that correcT?

Comment: On recurring events I use a `var isAppended = false`. Within the function I set it to `true` and do `if (!isAppended) {...}`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Yes Matt Busche.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: j08691 thnaks for responding! I'm not quite sure how to insert the html into my post.  I'm a straight-up noob!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the function handler after it's been executed. I gave the anonymous function a name for easier reference.

```
$(function () {
    if ($('div#dropmenu').length == 0) {
        $('#site_nav > ul > a').live('mouseenter', function f() {
            $(this).append("<div></div>");
            $('#site_nav > ul > li a div').attr('id', 'dropmenu');
            $('div#dropmenu').html("<ul></ul>");
            $('div#dropmenu ul').html("<li><a>Mission</a></li><li><a>Story</a></li><li><a>Quality</a></li><li><a>Pledge</a></li><li><a>Bio</a></li>");
            $(this).die('mouseenter', f);
        });
    } else {
        $('#site_nav > ul > li > a').append("");
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/die/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.one()` jQuery method to ensure that the event handler is executed only once.

```
$(function () {
    if ($('div#dropmenu').length == 0) {
        $('#site_nav > ul > a').one('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).append("<div></div>");
            $('#site_nav > ul > li a div').attr('id', 'dropmenu');
            $('div#dropmenu').html("<ul></ul>");
            $('div#dropmenu ul').html("<li><a>Mission</a></li><li><a>Story</a></li><li><a>Quality</a></li><li><a>Pledge</a></li><li><a>Bio</a></li>");
        });
    } else {
        $('#site_nav > ul > li > a').append("");
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This looks like such a cool fix, but not working for me.  In this case the div isn't appearing at all.  Am i missing something?  I appreciate the help, Rick!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `$('div#dropmenu').length == 0)` before you attach the event listener, after that, the listener is attached and will always execute. You can move the check inside the event listener.

```
$(function () {
    $('#site_nav > ul > a').live('mouseenter', function () {
        if ($('div#dropmenu').length == 0) {
            $(this).append("<div></div>");
            $('#site_nav > ul > li a div').attr('id', 'dropmenu');
            $('div#dropmenu').html("<ul></ul>");
            $('div#dropmenu ul').html("<li><a>Mission</a></li><li><a>Story</a></li><li><a>Quality</a></li><li><a>Pledge</a></li><li><a>Bio</a></li>");
        } else {
            $('#site_nav > ul > li > a').append("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Dang, this makes so much sense, but now I'm not seeing my div.  Any more clues?  Thanks, John S!

Comment: @melmac17 - I think you also need to change `$('#site_nav > ul > a')` to `$('#site_nav > ul > li > a')`.